# Fixed column using Jquery (issue with table headers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table and I need the first column of the table to be fixed so I can scroll all the way the the right and see the information related to any record of the first column, when I try to scroll the first column is ok, but it also put as fixed the next two headers of my table.

This is my jquery:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.tableHeadFixer = function(param) {
    var defaults = {
        head: true,
        foot: false,
        left: 0,
        right: 0
    };

    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, param);

    return this.each(function() {
        settings.table = this;
        settings.parent = $("<div></div>");
        setParent();

        if(settings.head == true)
            fixHead();

        if(settings.left > 0)
            fixLeft();

        // self.setCorner();

        $(settings.parent).trigger("scroll");

        $(window).resize(function() {
            $(settings.parent).trigger("scroll");
        });
    });

    function setTable(table) {

    }


    function setParent() {
        var container = $(settings.table).parent();
        var parent = $(settings.parent);
        var table = $(settings.table);

        table.before(parent);
        parent.append(table);
        parent
            .css({
                'width' : '100%',
                'height' : container.css("height"),
                'overflow' : 'scroll',
                'max-height' : container.css("max-height"),
                'min-height' : container.css("min-height"),
                'max-width' : container.css('max-width'),
                'min-width' : container.css('min-width')
            });

        parent.scroll(function() {
            var scrollWidth = parent[0].scrollWidth;
            var clientWidth = parent[0].clientWidth;
            var scrollHeight = parent[0].scrollHeight;
            var clientHeight = parent[0].clientHeight;
            var top = parent.scrollTop();
            var left = parent.scrollLeft();

            if(settings.head)
                this.find("thead tr > *").css("top", top);

            if(settings.left > 0)
                settings.leftColumns.css("left", left);

        }.bind(table));
    }

    function fixHead () {
        var thead = $(settings.table).find("thead");
        var tr = thead.find("tr");
        var cells = thead.find("tr > *");

        setBackground(cells);
        cells.css({
            'position' : 'relative'
        });
    }


    function fixLeft () {
        var table = $(settings.table);

        var fixColumn = settings.left;

        settings.leftColumns = $();

        for(var i = 1; i <= fixColumn; i++) {
            settings.leftColumns = settings.leftColumns
                .add(table.find("tr > *:nth-child(" + i + ")"));
        }

        var column = settings.leftColumns;

        column.each(function(k, cell) {
            var cell = $(cell);

            setBackground(cell);
            cell.css({
                'position' : 'relative'
            });
        });
    }


    function setBackground(elements) {
        elements.each(function(k, element) {
            var element = $(element);
            var parent = $(element).parent();

            var elementBackground = element.css("background-color");
            elementBackground = (elementBackground == "transparent" || elementBackground == "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)") ? null : elementBackground;

            var parentBackground = parent.css("background-color");
            parentBackground = (parentBackground == "transparent" || parentBackground == "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)") ? null : parentBackground;

            var background = parentBackground ? parentBackground : "white";
            background = elementBackground ? elementBackground : background;

            element.css("background-color", background);
        });
    }
};
})(jQuery);
```

And I also put the example in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tht8bbbd/) on it the window dont let the example to scroll so if you load it locally and make the window small you'll be able so scroll and see the issue I mentioned before with the headers of the table

Hope someone help me on this!

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested, this is possible simply with just a HTML and CSS solution, no JS. Much easier to implement, and also works cross browser will no bugs like what your above JS may produce.

**CSS:**

```
section {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-top: 37px;
  background: #500;
}
section.positioned {
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  width:800px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #333;
}
.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width:100%;
}
td + td {
  border-left:1px solid #eee;
}
td, th {
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
th {
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
th div{
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 25px;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -25px;
  line-height: normal;
  border-left: 1px solid #800;
}
th:first-child div{
  border: none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<section class="">
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr class="header">
          <th>
            Table attribute name
            <div>Table attribute name</div>
          </th>
          <th>
            Value
            <div>Value</div>
          </th>
          <th>
            Description
            <div>Description</div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>align</td>
          <td>left, center, right</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies the alignment of a table according to surrounding text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>bgcolor</td>
          <td>rgb(x,x,x), #xxxxxx, colorname</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies the background color for a table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>border</td>
          <td>1,""</td>
          <td>Specifies whether the table cells should have borders or not</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

**[WORKING EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/)**

Comment: Thanks for your time,

I check your example, the headers are ok, but I also need the first column to be static, like you in an Excel file, that the first column is static and you scroll all over the other columns.

Comment: Why don't you use a JS plugin such as [data tables](https://datatables.net/)? There is a great example [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/two_columns.html) that allows for the fixing of headers and multiple columns. The plugin is also great for filtering data, searching, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I saw that plug in but I really need to do it this way :(